# git send-email died of signal 11

Tags: git, email, sendmail, git-send-email

I am trying to use git send-email, which i used before whitout errors, but out of nowhere i got:

```
error: git send-email died of signal 11
```

right after he asked me if i want to send this email and i entered my password.

I have not changed my gitconfig since the last time i used send-email and --dry-run works perfectly.

```
[sendemail]
    smtpencryption = tls
    smtpserver = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpuser = <my-email>@gmail.com
    smtpserverport = 587
```

Unfortunately there is no additional output of GIT_TRACE=1 after entering my password:

```
Send this email? ([y]es|[n]o|[q]uit|[a]ll): y
trace: built-in: git 'credential' 'fill'
Password for 'smtp://<my-email>@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:587': 
error: git-send-email died of signal 11
```

I tried git send-email in different repositories, ending up with the same error.

My git version is 2.0.0

[**Edit**]: I updated my Git to version 2.1.0 now, but unfortunately this does not fix my error

[**Edit2**]: My git version is now 2.2.2 and i tried different email adresses and different protocols(IMAP/SMTP) with different ports to no effect

Can anybody tell me, what causes this error and in best case, how to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem, also started few days ago.